# How to keep information when I change layout android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, instance

Let's assume that my Android app has an activity_main.xml and a second_layout.xml.
In each of them there is a button and an editText.

The buttons allows me to change layout.
Any time I switch from a layout to another, the content of the ediTexts is deleted.
Can anyone tell me how to keep it?

I tried using the methods `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)`  and `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle outState)`  but it doesn't work.

Here's part of my code:

```
    editTextSingleLW = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSingleLW);
    String single_LW;

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putString("Single_LW",singleLW);

        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle outState){
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(outState);

        editTextSingleLW.setText(outState.getString("Single_LW")+"");
    }
```

Any idea?

Thank You very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

intead of using overriden `onRestoreInstanceState` use same restoring code in [`onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)) using its `savedInstanceState` argument. best approach would be to implement shared method for restoring data and call it in both `onCreate` and `onRestoreInstanceState` (remember to check `if` `Bundle` is `null`, as at very first start of `Activity` it is in `onCreate`)

Comment: I tried what you said but it still doesn't work. Actually it doesn't get in the onCreate method when I switch layout (I debugged it). The method I use to change layout is: ```setContentView(R.layout.second_layout);``` or ```setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);``` .

Comment: how do you switch this layout?

Comment: ```setContentView(R.layout.second_layout);``` or ```setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);```

Comment: before each `setContentView` call store data (e.g. text from `EditText`) in some local variable, after call get again reference to current `EditText` with `findViewById`, then set text to it. changing layout by `setContentView` doesn't make `Activity` recreate, so saving instance won't happen in here, `Activity` is still in resumed state

Comment: It seems working. Basically anytime I call ```setContentView``` I also have to call ```findViewById```. I wish there was a more convenient way. Than You anyway

Comment: same id for two views doesn't make these views are same instances. note when you call `setContentView`, then `findViewById`, then again `setContentView` with same layout id then you must again call `findViewById`, as `setContentView` destroys all current `View`s and creating new ones from scratch